# semantic-ui dropdown not close after open Angular2

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, semantic-ui

I am using semantic-ui dropdown in my Angular2 project but its not working properly. First, I write $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown('refresh'); in ngOnInit() but dropdown is not working. After that I write this in  ngAfterContentChecked() and its working but after open the dropdwon list its not close.

app.component.html

```
<button type="button" (click)="updateArrayCount() ">
    UpdateArray
</button>
 <div *ngFor="let x of arrayCount">
          <div class="ui selection dropdown">
            <div class="default text">None Selected</div>
            <div class="menu" *ngIf="data && data.name">
              <div *ngFor="let items of data.name" data-value="1">{{items}}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>     
 </div>
```

app.component.ts

```
arrayCount: Array<any> = [0];
updateArrayCount() {
this.arrayCount.push(this.arrayCount.length);
}
ngAfterViewChecked() {
 $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown('refresh');
}
```

Comment: Please, provide more code. What does your typescript file look like? And Your HTML-template?

Comment: i updated the code check once